# Minimize $\|\mathbf{x-y}\|^2 $ subject to $x \in $ set $S=\{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n \;\;\;\mid \;\;\; \|\mathbf{x-x_c}\|^2\leq r^2 \}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker

We are given the set $S=\{\mathbf{x}  \in \mathbb{R}^n \;\;\;\mid \;\;\; \|\mathbf{x-x_c}\|^2\leq r^2  \}$ and a point $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Our goal is to find point $\mathbf{\hat{x}}$ which minimizes $\|\mathbf{x-y}\|_2^2$.

- If $\|\mathbf{x-y}\|_2^2\leq r^2$ then point $\mathbf{y}$ lies in set and the distance is $0$
- If $\|\mathbf{x-y}\|_2^2 > r^2$ then point $\mathbf{y}$ lies somewhere outside of $S$. That means the the point in question $\mathbf{\hat{x}}$ must be on the set S , so it follows that  $\|\mathbf{\hat{x}-x_c}\|^2=r^2$

Finally, the problem can be formulated as 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{x}{\text{minimize}}
& & f_0(x)=\|\mathbf{x-y}\|^2 \\
& \text{subject to}
& & h(x) = \|\mathbf{x-x_c}\|^2-r^2=0 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

What optimization method can I use to solve the above problem? I have solved problems with linear equlity constraints but this problem is quadratically constrained.

Is there any way to transform the problem to be linearly constrained?

Comment: But you have already the tag "lagrange-multiplier". Anyways, $h(x)=0$ if and only if $\|\mathbf{x-x_c}\|=r$. Is this comment helpful?

Comment: @Jonas I know the KKT conditions for the problem are $\nabla f_0(\mathbf{\hat{x}})+\lambda \nabla h(\mathbf{\hat{x}})=0$ and $h(\mathbf{\hat{x}})=0$ but I am not sure how to continue.. I want to solve the problem with Newton's method but I can not with the quadratic constraint.

Answer (score 0):

The projection onto balls is well known and has a closed form.
As observed, when you are in the ball, then $\hat{x}=y$.
If $y$ is outside the ball, then move on the linesegment
connecting $y$ and the center $x_c$ until you hit the boundary
of the ball:
$$ \hat{x} = x_c + r\frac{y-x_c}{\|y-x_c\|}.$$